# Windows Task Scheduler - 2 Concurrent Tasks with the Same .exe

Tags: windows, triggers, taskscheduler

Is it possible to run multiple instances of an exe using task scheduler in Windows?

For example, Task A runs program.exe at 2 am, does part of a task, goes to sleep for 1/2 hour, and then resumes and finishes.  Task B runs program.exe at 2:15 am, goes sleep for 15 mins, then resumes and finishes.

Would this work or would there be conflicts?

Using Windows 7 and Windows 10.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: they are in different memory space, so it is technically possible, unless they are going to use the same resource then you may get resource contention issues

Comment: By resource do you mean program.exe or the things program.exe is working on?  From your reply it sounds like the later but I just wanted to be sure I understood. thx.

Comment: the latter, unless the application is coded as a single instance app